# "No such file or directory:" error when using Keras to load images

Tags: keras

I am following [this tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) to build a image binary classifier. Following the instructions, my code below is trying to load an image "test_00000.png" in order to randomly generate 20 transformations of the original image:

```python
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

img = load_img('/Users/Steven/data/image_data/test_00000.png')  # this is a PIL image
x = img_to_array(img)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (3, 150, 150)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (1, 3, 150, 150)

# the .flow() command below generates batches of randomly transformed images
# and saves the results to the `preview/` directory
i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1,
                          save_to_dir='/Users/Steven/data/image_data/preview', save_prefix='test', save_format='png'):
    i += 1
    if i > 20:
        break  # otherwise the generator would loop indefinitely
```

But I got an error:

```python
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf.py", line 28, in <module>
    save_to_dir='/Users/Steven/data/image_data/preview', save_prefix='test', save_format='png'):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 1069, in __next__
    return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 1189, in next
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 1171, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    img.save(os.path.join(self.save_to_dir, fname))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1932, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Steven/data/image_data/preview\\test_0_2149.png'
```

I have manually built a folder named "preview" in /User/Steven/data/image_data, which is why I don't understand how this error occurs. Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue and I think the reason is the API call has changed a little bit. Instead one can use :

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    path, grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb', target_size=None,
    interpolation='nearest' )
```

remember to change the path :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct path should be

```
'C:\\Users\\Steven\\data\\image_data\\preview\\test_0_2149.png'
```

You forget the partition letter `C:\\`

P.S.: I was having a similar problem on Windows and discovered that the full paths of some of my images had more than `260` characters, which is a limitation on Windows. My solution was to move the folder to a shallowest path.